# Pyplots imshow divides color channels

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, plot, keras

I want to apply a short pipeline to the galaxy zoo images by cropping and downsampling. To see the result I wrote a script with the following function

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

def test_plot():
    img = load_img('path/to/imgfile')
    pic1 = (img_to_array(img)/255.).reshape((424, 424, 3))

    img = img.crop(box=( (424-212)//2, (424-212)//2, (424-212)//2 + 212, (424-212)//2 + 212) )
    img.thumbnail((72, 72))
    pic2 = (img_to_array(img)/255.).reshape((72, 72, 3))

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=False, figsize=(12,7))
    ax1.imshow(pic1)
    ax2.imshow(pic2)
    fig.show()
```

The original image looks like this

[image]

and the result of the code looks like this

[image]

It seems like it's dividing the channels and plots them adjacent to each other. It should be noted that that isn't the case when I'm using my jupyter notebook which uses the same packages and the same environment. The output of the notebook looks like this

[image]

Comment: If it works in one environment and doesn't in another that's mostly because of different versions in use. We don't know which versions of the respective libraries you use here. In addition to that, you might want to report what `print((img_to_array(img)/255.).shape)` gives.

Comment: Sry for the late answer. Actually the version seems to be the issue. It seems that I set up the environment differently so that the output of `print((img_to_array(img)/255.).shape)` is (3, 424, 424) and (3, 72, 72) respectively in the script and (424, 424, 3) and (72, 72, 3) in the notebook. Reshaping in the script then leads to triplication of each channel. Thanks alot!